# How to transform this XML file with XSL I'm getting this error "lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Invalid type"

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xslt, lxml

I'm trying to transform the XML file with XSL using lxml library but I'm getting error **"lxml.etree.XSLTApplyError: Invalid type"**.

Not sure what's happening here. Any suggestions will be helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Here is my XSL,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:param name="input-path"/>
    <xsl:param name="result-document"/>
    <xsl:param name="dtd-path" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-namespace">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name(/*)='Message'">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input-string" select="namespace-uri(/*)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="string-to-find" select="'reference'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement-string" select="'short'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input-string" select="namespace-uri(/*)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="string-to-find" select="'short'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement-string" select="'reference'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="input-string"/>
        <xsl:param name="string-to-find"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement-string"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($input-string,$string-to-find)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input-string,$string-to-find)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$replacement-string"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input-string" select="substring-after($input-string,$string-to-find)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="string-to-find" select="$string-to-find"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement-string" select="$replacement-string"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$input-string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header>
   <Sender>
      <SenderName>CBS - Paris - Demo</SenderName>
      <EmailAddress>Testsupport@Test.com</EmailAddress>
   </Sender>
   <SentDateTime>20200718T1356Z</SentDateTime>
   <DefaultLanguageOfText>eng</DefaultLanguageOfText>
</Header>
<Product>
   <RecordReference>COM.test.12345678</RecordReference>
   <NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
</Product>
```

Here is my code,

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xsltfile = ET.XSLT(ET.parse('xsl_file.xsl'))
xmlfile = ET.parse("file1.xml")
output = xsltfile(xmlfile).write_output('test1.xml')
```

Comment: `xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"` looks suspicious. You should use 1.0.

Comment: Same error @mzjn

Comment: What is the XSLT supposed to do? It has a named template and a global variable, both unused.

Comment: Purpose is to convert all the tags to lowercase @MartinHonnen

Comment: The input you posted here is not a well-formed XML document: it has no single root element.--- *"Purpose is to convert all the tags to lowercase"* It does nothing of the kind.

Comment: You should avoid nesting and chaining multiple methods together for debugging purposes. `parse` should have erred on that non-well-formed markup. XSLT does not appear to do anything but define objects. Be sure to set up a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Start from:

```
import lxml.etree as et
```

The first correction pertains to your source XML.
Properly formatted XML should have a **single** root node
and all child nodes included in it.

So read your source XML as:

```
xmlTree = et.XML('''\
<Main>
    <Header>
        <Sender>
            <SenderName>CBS - Paris - Demo</SenderName>
            <EmailAddress>Testsupport@Test.com</EmailAddress>
        </Sender>
        <SentDateTime>20200718T1356Z</SentDateTime>
        <DefaultLanguageOfText>eng</DefaultLanguageOfText>
    </Header>
    <Product>
        <RecordReference>COM.test.12345678</RecordReference>
        <NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
    </Product>
</Main>''')
```

The second correction is to the content of the XSLT script.

To change element names to lowercase you should use a template matching `*`
(an element) and within it create the output element using *translate* function.
You can not use *lower-case()* function, as it works in XSLT version *2.0*,
whereas *lxml* supports version *1.0*.

The script should also contain the *identity template*.

So to read your source XSLT, run:

```
xsltTree = et.XML('''\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>''')
```

Then proceed as follows:

```
transform = et.XSLT(xsltTree)    # Create the XSLT transformer
result = transform(xmlTree)      # Transform source XML tree
```

To see the result you can run:

```
print(et.tostring(result, encoding='unicode'))
```

The result is:

```
<main>
    <header>
        <sender>
            <sendername>CBS - Paris - Demo</sendername>
            <emailaddress>Testsupport@Test.com</emailaddress>
        </sender>
        <sentdatetime>20200718T1356Z</sentdatetime>
        <defaultlanguageoftext>eng</defaultlanguageoftext>
    </header>
    <product>
        <recordreference>COM.test.12345678</recordreference>
        <notificationtype>03</notificationtype>
    </product>
</main>
```

with all element names changed to **lower** case.